# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error when connecting to Mongolab over VPN

Tags: express, vpn, mlab

This is only occurring when I'm on a VPN on my Win 7 machine. Outside VPN, on any public or private wifi connection, everything runs fine.

```
C:\node\ultronnode2\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dsXXXXXX.mongolab.com
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

Any idea how can I connect my Express app with Mongolab over VPN?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved: Apparently it is because of firewall issue. My firewall was restricting calls to dsXXXXX.mongolab.com [the connection uri]. Two solutions - If you know the network admin, ask him/her to poke a hole in the firewall for you or use local db, which worked for me since my app was  only for demonstration purposes.